# How to use member in both instance method and class method

Tags: swift

```
class MyClass:NSObject {

      var member = "abc"
      func instanceMethod(){
            print("\(member)")
       }
      class func classMethod(){
            print("\(member)")
       }
 }
```

I want to access "member" in both methods.

Comment: **(1)** Make sure you add an initializer to initialize `member` property of your class (or initialize with a default value) **(2)** you can access `member` by prefixing with `self` keyword, e.g. `self.member`, _in your instance method_, **(3)** both your print statements are missing a trailing paranthesis `)`. **(4)** For your `class` (static) function, you cannot access an `instance property`, as this is naturally connected to an _instance of the class itself_, whereas a class (static) function only refers to the _type_ of the class (an no _instance_ of it).

Comment: You can make member static variable that is shared across all instances of MyClass and you access it with: MyClass.member.

Comment: Thanks dfri, I have correct my question as per your suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do that will be by using a singleton or a static member of the same type:

```
class MyClass: NSObject {

      static var sharedInstance : MyClass?
      var member:String

      func instanceMethod(){
            print("\(MyClass.sharedInstance?.member)"
      }

      static func classMethod(){
            print("\(sharedInstance?.member)"
      }
 }
```